# Why should I commit and not push in Git?

Tags: git

I've googled a lot but I can't find an answer.

For what I've understood, a commit should be applied each time a file is edited. Explaining what was the edit, why, etc.
Then I should push the commit to make the server version of the file synced.

What I can't understand is:

Why should I commit and not immediately push a file I've edited?

Comment: 1. You're not online right now. 2. You're working on a project that involves emailing patches. 3. You want to rebase your changes into a less messy state before pushing. 4. Your remote repository is on a slow server or across a slow connection, you want to continue working and only push things when you go grab a coffee. Probably many more. Git is designed to allow a lot of flexibility when it comes to workflow, disconnecting "recording changes to a repository", and "exchanging changes between repositories" is one of the ways they achieve this.

Comment: Add to that 4) You committed to a local branch that doesn't even exist on the server.

Comment: Honestly, there's so many valid reasons to want to do those things separately that the question should be "why does SVN tie those two operations together?"

Comment: It depends how you view version control in general. If you appreciate that it isn't only about publishing your changes, but also about helping you to keep track of (possibly half-done) modifications not pushing becomes much clearer.

Comment: Thank you for all the answers, looks a lot clearer now.

Comment: Or, to put it another way: "record changes then immediately send changes to a remote server" is, admittedly, a very very common thing to want to do. (Which is why most Git GUI tools let you do that conveniently.) But logically they are two separate operations, and thus situations arise where you might want to do them separately. This is why git lets you opt-in to joining those two together, rather than making that the only behaviour.

Comment: @millimoose please covert your comments into an answer to not leave question unanswered.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is true that a very common thing you want to do when working with version control is: "record changes into a commit, then send that commit to a remote server". In fact, most Git GUI tools probably let you do this in one step. However, logically, "record changes into a commit", and "publish commit to a server" are distinct operations. In Subversion, only the server keeps track of commits, so you have to send the changes to it for this to happen. In Git, the local repository keeps track of commits as well, so it's possible to split them up.

Now, while doing the two in a single step is a common workflow, there are many situations when you might want to do something else:

1. You're not online at the moment, or the remote server happens to be down, or your connection to it is slow for some reason. I.e. sending changes is either technically impossible, or would interrupt your work and disrupt your concentration for too long. In this case want to delay publishing commits until later, but you want to keep working (and making commits) until then.
2. You expect you'll have to merge in changes from coworkers. This is a very big context switch from working on your code, and similarly to the situation above, you might want to delay this until you're done with your task so you can stay focused on it. (This, in fact, tends to be a very common problem in Subversion teams - the mentality that "merging is annoying" that makes people do one commit with all their day's work when they leave, without really resolving conflicts properly. Since resolving conflicts is easier with "nice" commits with a clear purpose, this creates a vicious cycle.)
3. You're contributing to a project by emailing patches. (This is how the Linux kernel used to be developped, and maybe still is. This requirement in fact influenced Git's design early on.)
4. You're making very frequent commits and maybe pushing them to a private remote repository for backup purposes. However, you want to use `git rebase` to clean them up before publishing them - say, bundling a new feature with fixes to bugs found in the initial implementation into a single commit.
5. A nitty-gritty reason: you're committing to a feature branch that doesn't even exist on the remote server yet so there's nothing to push to. (Which is desired as well, feature branches don't necessarily need to be published widely.)

Basically, Git strives for maximal flexibility in order to support arbitrarily complex workflows. Now, you might not need this, in which case you can easily use GUIs or small shell scripts that will combine the stuff you need.

Comment: To add, I sometimes hold back commits, to not trigger the CI, until I'm very sure my code is clean, and has tests on it.

Answer (score 0):

The above answer is great, but there is one more important reason that I do this - Sometimes, while doing local testing on one branch, I would like to have custom configurations, but these configs should not be sent over to the actual remote repository. In that case, committing it locally has helped me keep that configuration safe.